# Linear term in NLSM action, expansion in terms of geodesic tangent vectors

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, field-theory, action, sigma-models

The current question has arised as I started reading the [the book by Ketov](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=24BBE2E7343E58BE5C95D185654EA706).

We define the NLSM action as (for simplicity, I also assume $g_{ab}=g_{ba}$ and also the vanishing torsion):
\begin{equation}
    S[\phi] = \dfrac{1}{2\lambda^2}\int \mathrm{d}^Dx \,g_{ab}(\phi) (\partial^\mu \phi^a)(\partial_\mu \phi^b)
\end{equation}
The Euler-Lagrange equations of motion are obtained from:
\begin{equation}
    \dfrac{\partial S}{\partial \phi}
    = \dfrac{\partial g_{ab}}{\partial\phi^c}(\partial^\mu \phi^a)(\partial_\mu \phi^b)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    \partial^\mu \left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial (\partial^\mu \phi^c)}\right)
    = \partial^\mu \left(2 g_{ab} \delta^a_c (\partial_\mu \phi^b) \right) 
    = \partial^\mu \left(2 g_{ac}  (\partial_\mu \phi^a) \right)
    = 2 (\partial^\mu g_{ac})  (\partial_\mu \phi^a) + 2 g_{ac} (\Box \phi^a)
\end{equation}
Which gives us:
\begin{equation}
    \text{EOM} [\phi] =
    \dfrac{\partial g_{ab}}{\partial\phi^c}(\partial^\mu \phi^a)(\partial_\mu \phi^b)
    - 2 (\partial^\mu g_{ac})  (\partial_\mu \phi^a) - 2 g_{ac} (\Box \phi^a) =0
\end{equation}
(not sure how to simplify the expression above further, it can probably be written nicely in terms of Christoffels)

Now, if we were to expand the action around the configuration $\phi_{\text{cl}}$ which obeys the equation of motion written above, the first term in the expansion would be proportional to ${\text{EOM}[\phi_{c}]}$, and would trivially vanish.

Ketov, however, offers a smarter choice rather that simply using the deviation from the classical configuration $\pi = \phi - \phi_{\text{cl}}$ as a small parameter. Namely, for the sake of covariance, he uses the unit vector $\xi$ along the geodesic in the target space which connects $\phi_{\text{cl}}$ and $\phi$ (for the flat metric this, of course, coincides with $\pi$). It is defined as:
\begin{gather}
    \dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}s^2} \rho^a(x,s) + \Gamma^a_{\;bc}[\rho] \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \rho^b \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \rho^c = 0
    \\ \rho(x, s=0) = \phi_{\text{cl}}(x) \quad,\qquad \rho(x, s=1) = \phi_{\text{cl}}(x) + \pi(x) \quad,\qquad
    \\ \xi^a_s = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \rho^a \quad
    \left.\xi^a_s\right|_{s=0} = \xi^a
\end{gather}

Should we expect the term, linear in $\xi$ in the expansion of the action, to be proportional to ${\text{EOM}[\phi_{c}]}$ and vanish as well? Its explicit form is:
\begin{gather}
    S_1[\phi] = \dfrac{1}{2\lambda^2}\int \mathrm{d}^Dx\left\{  - 2 \xi^a g_{ab} (D_\mu \partial^\mu \phi^b) \right\} \quad,
    \\ (D_\mu \xi_s)^a  = (\delta^{ab} \partial_\mu + \Gamma^a_{\;bc}\partial_\mu\rho^c) \xi^b_s
\end{gather}

I would guess so but not sure how to properly argue and prove this.